# TTS for digit 0-9

Tags: javascript

Could you please help with TTS for digit 0-9. How can i make my own TTS for digit 0-9. i have application where user will insert his mobile number and by using TTS I have repeat same number. By default my application use window TTS i.t english.

But I want to make for thai language.Could you help regarding this.

Comment: Who or what is "***TTS***", is it anything related to Drupal? Please edit your question to explain that. Also, is this abut Drupal 5, 6 or anything above that?

Comment: I take _TTS_ means [Text-To-Speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_synthesis). In this case, the question is too broad. Also, you aren't asking any explicit question, but describing what you are trying to achieve. What don't you understand in implementing what you describe? Keep in mind that requests for modules are off-topic for us, and that we don't give hints, but answer questions with a definitive answer.